# C++ no acceptable conversion for operator+ with class

Tags: visual-c++, operator-overloading

I have some 15-year-old C++ code that I am trying to bring up to more modern times. At this stage, I'm trying to get code that compiled with Visual C++ 6.0 to now compile with VS 2003 (Microsoft Visual C++ .NET 69462-335-0000007-18915). If we can get this to compile cleanly & run properly, then we can take another step to get it into a more recent version of VS.  But I'm having a number of problems...

Here is a snippet of the (simplified) code:

```
class toS
{
public:
    toS() { buff[0] ='\0'; }
    operator LPCTSTR() { return buff; }

protected:
    void Append (TCHAR c)
    {
        LPTSTR p = buff + _tcslen(buff);
        *p++ = c;
        *p = '\0';
    }
    TCHAR buff[40];
};

class LtoS : public toS
{
public:
    LtoS(LONG n, TCHAR c = '\0')
    {
        _ltot(n, buff, 10);
        Append(c);
    }
};

void WriteBool(const CString& Section, const CString& Key, bool Value);

CString Section;
int nLine = 0;
std::vector<bool> *BoolVect;
std::vector<bool>::iterator vi;
...
for (vi = BoolVect->begin(); vi != BoolVect->end(); vi++)
    WriteBool(Section, "LineVis " + LtoS(nLine++), *vi);
...
```

From this I get the following error message:

error C2677: binary '+' : no global operator found which takes type 'LtoS' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

**Any idea how this code ever worked?**  If I can find out what it did in the past, I can begin to define the overloaded operator+ to match the functionality.

Comment: It seems like `LtoS` is both a type and a function declared somewhere. There might not be enough information posted to give an answer here.

Comment: This should never have worked.

Comment: *However* I seem to remember VC++ 6 allowing things like passing a `CString` object to `printf` without any conversion, because its first member variable was the string so the compiler somehow generated code to use the first member implicitly. I even seem to remember (ab)using something like that in my own code at the time. It could be something like that going on here.

Comment: LtoS is the name of the class, so it's also the name of the constructor, which appears to be a function call here.

Answer (score 0):

Deriving from several of the comments, try adding a public conversion operator to `class toS` as follows:

```
operator LPCTSTR() const { return &buff[0]; }
```

You may need to explicitly construct the string in the `for` loop as well, e.g.:

```
WriteBool(Section, CString("LineVis ") + static_cast<LPCTSTR>(LtoS(nLine++)), *vi);
```

(**Side note**: As you probably know since you just extracted code for an example, there's a problem here:

`std::vector<bool> BoolVect;`

...

`for (vi = BoolVect->begin(); vi != BoolVect->end(); vi++)`

The notation you're using to access the `BoolVect` implies that it is a pointer, but it's not being declared as such in your example.)

Comment: Oops - good catch @Phil Brubaker, I messed up on the extraction of the code snippet.  Fixing it in the original question...

Comment: I also forgot to include the definition of operator LPCTSTR(), which is now added to the original question.

Comment: Ah so that operator already existed?  I'll update my answer slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler error goes away when I make class tos inherit from CString with:

```
class tos : public CString { ... }
```

Hopefully this will not only compile, but will execute correctly...